# How to render 2 .vtp slices in the same render Window

Tags: python, rendering, actor, vtk

I have to some slices in .vtp format (also in vtm) that i want to visualize together to work on them afterward.

I already set readers, mappers, actors, render window and camera coordinates, but when the image is rendered it gives me only the first slice (Slice10) and not the second (Slice11)

```
import vtk

colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()
Slice10 = 'Slice10_0_0.vtp'
reader1 = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader1.SetFileName(Slice10)

Slice11 = 'Slice11_0_0.vtp'
reader2 = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader2.SetFileName(Slice11)

# mapper
mapper1 = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper1.SetInputConnection(reader1.GetOutputPort())

mapper2 = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper2.SetInputConnection(reader2.GetOutputPort())

# actors
actor1 = vtk.vtkActor() 
actor1.SetMapper(mapper1)

actor2 = vtk.vtkActor()
actor2.SetMapper(mapper1)

'''RENDER'''
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
# Background
renderer.SetBackground(1., 1., 1.)
# Add actor to the scene
renderer.AddActor(actor1)
renderer.AddActor(actor2)

'''Render window'''
renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

'''Interactor'''
renderWindowInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderWindowInteractor.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

'''Add camera coordinates'''
axes = vtk.vtkAxesActor()
widget = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
widget.SetOutlineColor(0.9300, 0.5700, 0.1300)
widget.SetOrientationMarker(axes)
widget.SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor)
widget.SetViewport(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.4)
widget.SetEnabled(1)
widget.InteractiveOn()

# Reset camera
renderer.ResetCamera()

'''Begin interaction'''
renderWindow.Render()
renderWindowInteractor.Initialize()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
renderWindowInteractor.Start()
```

I expect to have the two slices in the same rendering window one over the other maybe with some distance but same center in order to save them together as an unique image and work on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, except that you set the same mapper for two different actors so actually you are displaying twice the same geometry (line 19 to 24). Change:

```
# actors
actor1 = vtk.vtkActor() 
actor1.SetMapper(mapper1)

actor2 = vtk.vtkActor()
actor2.SetMapper(mapper1)
```

to:

```
# actors
actor1 = vtk.vtkActor() 
actor1.SetMapper(mapper1)

actor2 = vtk.vtkActor()
actor2.SetMapper(mapper2)
```

And it will work.